# NodeJs - Detect whether app is on AWS or local

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way in NodeJs to detect whether it's currently running on an EC2 instance or whether it's being run locally? I have some functionality that changes based on where it's deployed. I can detect the IP address but I want something more dynamic, not tied to specific server configurations.

Comment: When you run nodeJS, it runs on a port. So the easiest way to know what environment you are on, is change the port that it runs on for each environment. EX. :3000 for local and :3010 for EC2. OR. you could create environment variables and change them for each environment

Comment: I was going to address it with environment variables, just a bIt annoying if i terminate a server, I have to redefine them. (unless there's a way to define them dynamically, haha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could hit [EC2 Metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html) to determine EC2 instance or not.

This curl woks only within an EC2 instance

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

Library [node-ec2-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ec2-metadata) exposes an easy to use method which calls this metadata service behind the scenes.

```
var metadata = require("node-ec2-metadata");

metadata.isEC2().then(function (onEC2) {
  console.log("Running on EC2? " + onEC2);
});
```

Point to keep in mind, straight from the docs(since they hit the HEAD url and timeout after 500ms):

> The initial call may take up to 500ms on a non-EC2 host, but the
> result is cached so subsequent calls provide a result immediately

Comment: Waw, that's a pretty spot-on solution, thank you

Comment: Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try checking for env variables, e.g.

```
if(process.env.PARTITION) {...}
if(process.env.NODE_ENV) {...}
if(process.env.PROJECT_ID) {...}
```

Or you can check `if .env file exist`, because this should be in your `.gitignore` and only be present on your ocal environment.